# GCP GKE cluster node throws {"unmanaged": {"fs.aio-nr": "2272", "net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen_key"

Tags: linux, tcp, google-kubernetes-engine

I recently installed on GKE [Botkube](https://github.com/infracloudio/botkube) and it started showing error of [image]
does anyone have any idea how to approach that issue or what would that mean ? I've read on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Fast_Open) on how fastopen helps to make client-server connection quicker on second re-try skiping the 3 way syn-ack but what could this error mean ?

Comment: Please update your question with the information about your `GKE` cluster (version, node type, node image, network setup, any additional options added). Are you seeing similar issues in Stackdriver, are there any other issues with this cluster? Have you installed this software with the link you provided? Any changes you made to it's configs?

Comment: @potatopotato I am getting the same error. Did you have any luck with the issue ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my GKE K8s cluster but no boktube, I'm seeing it in the Lens interface

Answer (score 5):

The messages you are seeing are the [TCP Fast Open (TFO)](https://lwn.net/Articles/508865/) encryption keys sent by the GKE node, and I'm assuming they are being marked as an error by Botkube because every time a new encryption key is generated, it's done by modifying a Linux Kernel parameter using the [Sysctl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sysctl.8.html) command, which might be a trigger.

As far as I understand, this is the normal behavior for TFO, and it is safe to disregard these messages.

A very good explanation on how the encryption keys for TFO are generated can be found on this [Serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1017584/how-to-set-tcp-fast-open-cookie-timeout).

Comment: Very interesting, thank you!