# GKE alert ("unmanaged": {"net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen_key") by botkube

Tags: kubernetes, networking, devops, google-kubernetes-engine, cluster-computing

We are deploying a GKE Cluster with terraform, we have installed a botkube to receive logs alert on a slack channel, and after a few days we receive many of these alert messages for each node randomly.

[botkube message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgIO0.png)

Some information about our cluster:

- Control Plane GKE Version: 1.21.5-gke.1302
- Node GKE Version: 1.20.11-gke.1300
- Node type: e2-medium
- Network Setup: VPC-NATIVE

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70959289/10344880) may answer your question:

> The messages you are seeing are the [TCP Fast Open (TFO)](https://lwn.net/Articles/508865/) encryption keys sent by the GKE node, and I'm assuming they are being marked as an error by Botkube because every time a new encryption key is generated, it's done by modifying a Linux Kernel parameter using the [Sysctl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sysctl.8.html) command, which might be a trigger.
>
> As far as I understand, this is the normal behavior for TFO, and it is safe to disregard these messages.
>
> A very good explanation on how the encryption keys for TFO are generated can be found on this [Serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1017584/how-to-set-tcp-fast-open-cookie-timeout).